# 6-bit CRC datasheet confusion STMicroelectronics L9963E

Tags: c++, embedded, spi, crc, serial-communication

I’m working on the SPI communication between a microcontroller and the L9963E. [The datasheet of the L9963E](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l9963e.pdf#page=36&zoom=100,0,646) shows little information about the CRC calculation, but mentions:

- a CRC of 6 bits,
- a polynomial of X<sup>6</sup>   + X<sup>4</sup>  + X<sup>3</sup>  + 1 = `0b1011001`
- a seed of `0b111000`

The documentation also mentions in the SPI protocol details that the CRC is a value between `0x00` and `0x3F`, and is "calculated on the [39-7] field of the frame", see [Table 22](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l9963e.pdf#page=30&zoom=100,0,499).

**I'm wondering: What is meant by "field [39-7]"?** The total frame length is 40bits, out of this the CRC makes up 6 bits. I would expect a CRC calculation over the remaining 34 bits, but field 39-7 would mean either 33 bits (field 7 inclusive) or 32 bits (excluding field 7).

Since I have access to a L9963E evaluation board, which includes pre-loaded firmware, I have hooked up a logic analyser. I have found the following example frames to be sent to the L9963E from the eval-board, I am assuming that these are valid, error-free frames.

```
0xC21C3ECEFD
0xC270080001
0xE330081064
0xC0F08C1047
0x827880800E
0xC270BFFFF9
0xC2641954BE
```

Could someone clear up the datasheet for me, and maybe advise me on how to implement this CRC calculation?

Comment: Did you mean "logic analyser" - I cannot see a purpose for a spectrum analyser here.  Is it possible that it is a typo, and that it should be bits 39-6, with 5-0 being the CRC?  It would be simple enough to test the examples.

Comment: Cheers mate, yeah logic analyser. Tired typo on my end, I suppose the same happened at ST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit ranges in datasheets like this are always inclusive.

I suspect that this is just a typo, or the person who wrote it temporarily forgot that the bits are numbered from zero.

Looking at the other bit-field boundaries in Table 19 of the document you linked it wouldn't make sense to exclude the bottom bit of the data field from the CRC, so I suspect the datasheet should say bits 39 to 6 inclusive.

There is a tool called [pycrc](https://pycrc.org/generator.html) that can generate C code to calculate a CRC with an arbitrary polynomial.

Comment: That would make sense, a small mistake on their end. I will contact ST and ask them for clarification. Thank you for the pycrc  tip

Answer (score 2):

All of the special frames have CRC == 0:

```
(0000000016 xor E000000000) mod 59 = 00
(C1FCFFFC6C xor E000000000) mod 59 = 00
(C1FCFFFC87 xor E000000000) mod 59 = 00
(C1FCFFFCDE xor E000000000) mod 59 = 00
(C1FCFFFD08 xor E000000000) mod 59 = 00
```

and as noted by Mark Adler only one of the messages in the question works:

```
(C270BFFFF9 xor E000000000) mod 59 = 00
```

Comment: Yes, but only one of the messages listed in the question works. I wonder if they read the data correctly.

Comment: Thank you both for your input. I will have a look at the way I’m reading the data. What is your opinion on the [39-7] field specification mentioned in the datasheet? Do you think, like Tom mentioned, that this a typo and should be [39-6]?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely 39-6, because that works for the examples in the document. Your data however is messed up.

Answer (score 1):

If a 40-bit message is in the low bits of `uint64_t x;`, then this:

```
    x ^= (uint64_t)0x38 << 34;
    for (int j = 0; j < 40; j++)
        x = x & 0x8000000000 ? (x << 1) ^ ((uint64_t)0x19 << 34) : x << 1;
    x &= 0xffffffffff;
```

gives `x == 0` for all of the example messages in the document. But only for one of your examples in the question. You may not be extracting the data correctly.