# 6 bit CRC error frame in STMicroelectronics L9963E

Tags: c, embedded, spi, crc

I am attempting to establish communication between an `L9963E` BMS IC and a `SPC57s501` microcontroller through `SPI`. I have configured all pins related to SPI communication on the `L9963E` to the microcontroller and it has started sending frames. However, after the `L9963E` wakes up through SPI communication (as indicated by 37 successful clock pulses in the datasheet) and sends the data frame `0x0000000016`, which is "After a Wakeup Event" frame, I tried to read the data registers by sending a read frame. The response I received was `0xC1FCFFFD08`, indicating a "CRC data Frame error or corrupted frame". Can anyone advise me on how to proceed further?

Comment: There is a lot of missing context. Do you have a shematic? Why does the L9963E send clock pulses, isn't that the job of the master which should be the µC? From where did you get the 0xC1FCFFFD08, where you do read that value? Did you use a logic analyser to control the SPI bus? Did you lower the clock rate to reduce the risk of EMC messing up your data, ....?

Comment: Regardless of the problem, its probably a good idea to connect a logic analyzer to the SPI lines and see what the data looks like on the line. Then its possible to manually verify the CRC that you see in the packet.

Comment: Adding some code in your question could help as well.

Comment: To paraphrase your question _"My code does not work, what could be wrong with my code"_.  If you don't think it is your code (it is), then your question is off-topic here. If it is your code, then clearly we need to see it to answer.  Occam's razor  suggests that you are calculating the CRC incorrectly.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 the values `0xC1FCFFFD08` is a CRC Error Frame type (in the datasheet), not some random bit sequence.  It would suggest there is no signal integrity issue (not the same as EMC, which is evel less likely), at least not on the MISO, and that the CRC was simply incorrect.

Comment: You have not accurately described the wake-up process.  It is not "indicated" by 37 SCK pulses, it is woken by 37 pulses - there is no direct indication of success.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73363252/6-bit-crc-datasheet-confusion-stmicroelectronics-l9963e, there is a clear typo in the datasheet that has not been corrected, and both answers provide a method of calculating the correct CRC.